# PROBLEMA CON STRING c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy haciendo un codigo con POO y cuando uso string como tipo de dato me marca este error
expected primary-expression before ´n´

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"empleados.h"
using namespace std;
empleados empleado[30];
int tam;
string n;
float m1,m2,m3,m4;
int main(){
    cout<<"CUANTOS EMPLEADOS DESEA: ";cin>>tam;
    for(int i=0;i>=tam;i++){
        cout<<"NOMBRE DEL EMPLEADO "<<i+1<<": ";getline(cin,n);
        cout<<"DIGITE EL VALOR DE LA VENTA DEL MES 1: ";cin>>m1;
        cout<<"DIGITE EL VALOR DE LA VENTA DEL MES 2: ";cin>>m2;
        cout<<"DIGITE EL VALOR DE LA VENTA DEL MES 3: ";cin>>m3;
        cout<<"DIGITE EL VALOR DE LA VENTA DEL MES 4: ";cin>>m4;
        empleado[i].setregistro(string n,float m1,float m2, float m3,float m4, int i);
    }

}
```

ya he probado cambiar la libreria string por string.h y por cstring

Comment: para empezar tienes un error de sintáxis en `empleado[i].setregistro(...)`. en la invocación de `setregistro` no se deben incluir los tipos de los argumentos. o sea: `empleado[i].setregistro(n, m1, m2, m3, m4, i);`

Comment: `string.h` y `cstring` son cabeceras diferentes a `string`. La funcionalidad de C++ implementada con clases y plantillas se encuentra en `string`. `string.h` contiene funciones de C y se mantiene por compatibilidad. `cstring` define las mismas funciones pero en el namespace `std`.